# 413 Request Entity Too Large error occur while uploading cookbook

Tags: chef-recipe

I found this error after i put a zip file into the cookbook and then uploaded it into the server. Can someone suggest me the right solution for this error...

```
ERROR: Failed to upload ~/chef-repo/cookbooks/api/files/default/xx.zip (82c4bebb9890545ead67c44dca9f5a1f) to https://x.xxx.x.xxx:443/bookshelf/organization-9765dffbae2bea820ff192869963766f/checksum-82c4bebb9890545ead67c44dca9f5a1f?AWSAccessKeyId=970f9481256ced719247e5d4223442e56ac82b19&Expires=1519812888&Signature=szLz9tUlabOE8vck7Rug9cjUH%2B8%3D : 413 "Request Entity Too Large"
 ERROR: Request Entity Too Large
Response: <html>
<head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.11.2.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Chef to host any 'big' files. Setup additional HTTP server or use off site storage like S3.

Comment: Thank you...Can't we upload zip files directly  into cookbook in files directory?

Comment: You can, but you should not. Chef server is not 'artiface' storage, it is not jack of all trades. As you can see it has some limits.

Comment: Thank you.But i want to upload 500mb size file directly to cookbook for some  config problems .i can able to upload  250mb size file into cookbook only.i increased the value of  nginx['client_max_body_size'] and opscode_solr4['max_field_length'].Eventhough it dosen't work to me to upload 500mb size file.Can you tell me any solution for it.