# How Can i Upload 500mb size file into chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I want to upload 500MB size file directly to cookbook for some config problems. I only able to upload 250MB size file into cookbook. I've increased the value of nginx`['client_max_body_size']` and `opscode_solr4['max_field_length']`.Eventhough it doesn't work for me to upload 500mb size file.
Can anyone give me some solution for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [413 Request Entity Too Large error occur while uploading cookbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028024/413-request-entity-too-large-error-occur-while-uploading-cookbook)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. This is not what Chef is for and our storage and file sync layers are not efficient enough to do it well. Put the file on a web server somewhere and use a `remote_file` resource instead of a `cookbook_file`.

Comment: Thank you.you are right.But our product configuration purpose  i want to upload 500mb file into cookbook repository.Is there no way to upload it ?

Comment: No, that is 100% not supported. Do not do it.

Comment: @coderanger I'm trying to understand the rationale behind this. Why is Chef limited in this manner while alternatives like Puppet do not have such limitations (at least at this level of file sizes)? AFAIR Chef did not have similar limitations in the older versions.

Comment: Chef Server is not a dedicated file server and so it is not very good at being a file server. There are much better tools to use and the design of Chef is to coordinate tools rather than replace them.